# jQuery plugin accessing information how to?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jquery-plugins

For example I have a plugin for a list of elements:

```
<ul id="list_elements">
 <li>1 element</li>
 <li>2 element</li>
 <li>3 element</li>
 <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

jQuery code using the plugin:

```
$('#list_elements').loadElementsPlugin();
```

If the loadElementsPlugin has a function (getElementsCount()), you can call that function doing something like this:

```
var myvar = $('#list_elements').loadElementsPlugin();
alert( 'My count is ' + myvar.getElementsCount() );
```

But, if you want to call that function from the same HTML code, how you can do it?

For example:

```
 <ul id="list_elements">
     <li>1 element</li>
     <li>2 element</li>
     <li>3 element</li>
     <li>...</li>
     <li><input type="button" onclick='alert( ??????.getElementsCount() );'/></li>
    </ul>
```

I hope you understand my question....

Comment: You should accept answers to your questions.

Comment: if you don't accept answers to your questions, people wont want to help you, go back through all your questions and accept the best answers. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use method chaining. So your loadElementsPlugin should return a jQuery object

$('#list_elements')
  .loadElementsPlugin()
  .getElementsCount()

Answer (score 0):

This is bad practice; you should use jQuery click handlers.
Do not mix script with presentation.

---

To answer the question, you can do that the same way you call the plugin elsewhere.
In addition, since `this` will refer to the element that you clicked on, you can also write `$(this).closest('ul').getElementsCount()`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're asking how to use your plugin and have it refer to the list from within which it's being called. If so, try something like this:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
  $('ul').find('button') // for each button inside a list
      .click( function(e){ // attach this click behavior
        e.preventDefault(); 
        $(this).closest('ul') // this list
            .loadElementsPlugin().getElementsCount(); // apply your plugin
    });
});
```

This handles multiple lists, if you have them, and gets rid of inline event handlers, which should be avoided.